# Conditional style not working

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, iis

I need conditional styling depending on whether the browser is IE or not.

Approach 1

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style>
   .myDiv{background-color: #0F0;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
  <style>
   .myDiv{background-color: #000;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Approach 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunc()
  {
    if ($.browser.msie) // Internet Explorer
    {
       $(".myDiv").css("background-color", "#0F0");
    }
    else // Other browsers
    {
       $(".myDiv").css("background-color", "#000");
    }
    return false;
  }
  window.onload  = myFunc;
</script>
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 200px;">Hello</div>
```

Both approaches work fine when I host the code in local or testing servers. But they just doesn't work when I run them on the prod machine.

When I open the browser console (for approach 2), I can see something like this when hosted in local or test server

```
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 200px;" jQuery15487254606012953487="4">
  Hello
</div>
```

And when hosted in the problematic server, I see this in the console

```
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 200px;">
  Hello
</div>
```

Could this difference hint to anything that I'm missing?

I use the following

- jquery-1.3.1.min.js
- IIS 8.5.9748.0 in both local and server
- Asp.net with C#

Comment: have you tried to clean browser cache?

Comment: Not sure about the browser sniffing JS, but I don't think newer IE supports conditional comments any more (since IE10 if I remember correctly). If I had to guess why it's working on your local environment and not on live, I'd guess you're missing the `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"` meta tag and your browser is running in compatibility mode locally, so it's rendering as an older version of the browser that did support those methods.

Comment: @Daniel H Yes I have. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

When you say `window.onload  = myFunc();`, you're calling `myFunc` immediately -- possibly before there are even any elements to style.

Replace `myFunc()` with `myFunc` (no parens) in order to set the handler. Or, even better, say `$(myFunc)` and stop farting around with `window.onload` entirely.

Aside from that, [`$.browser` has been removed from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/). If you insist on caring about which browser is in use, take a look at [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator). (But frankly, there is no good reason to care anymore, and some very good reasons *not* to care.)

Comment: Removing the parentheses didn't help.

Comment: That's because `$.browser` no longer exists. Browser sniffing itself is deprecated in favor of feature testing, but if you insist, i've edited my answer to mention how to do it.